# How to `go install` to bin inside module dir?

Tags: go

For example, when I run this

```
GOOS="windows" GOARCH="386" go install ./something
```

The executable would be created at

```
$GOROOT/bin/$GOOS_$GOARCH/something.exe
```

I want the executable to be created at

```
path/to/my/module/bin/$GOOS_$GOARCH/something.exe
```

**EDIT**

To clarify, I ask the question in the context of cross compiled builds inside a module.

I get the desired result using this command inside my module. I'd like to avoid specifying the path.

```
GOOS="windows" GOARCH="386" go build -o ./bin/$GOOS_$GOARCH/something.exe ./something
```

So, is it possible to get the same with `go install`?

Setting GOBIN results in an error

```
GOBIN=$(pwd)/bin GOOS="windows" GOARCH="386" go install ./something
# go install: cannot install cross-compiled binaries when GOBIN is set
```

Comment: `go help install`: "Executables are installed in the directory named by the GOBIN environment variable, which defaults to $GOPATH/bin or $HOME/go/bin if the GOPATH environment variable is not set."

Comment: Also consider merely using `go build -o path/to/executable/image` instead of `go install`; the latter is basically `go build` followed by `mv`.

Comment: As Peter hinted, please do not ignore `go help <command>`: this documentation system has reasonable cross-linking, so after reading help on `go install` you'd naturally read the help page of `go build` and finally had no need to post here on SO and spend your own and everyone else's time to discuss a rather trivial problem.

Comment: @kostix FYI I did read the docs, did you try to run the commands? I'm trying to maintain an abandoned open source project that uses `go install` in it's Makefile. I've converted it to a module with dependencies in ./vendor, just in case some of them disappear. I can change the Makefile to use `go build` with manually specified path, but I'd like to avoid that, seeing as `go install` is also smart about adding an appropriate extension (exe in this case).

Comment: (Re-reading after edits). I think the refusal of the toolset to use `GOBIN` is kind of sensible: it's supposed to be for the host's native GOOS and GOARCH. Judging from the `go help build`'s statement that «The '.exe' suffix is added when writing a Windows executable.», I think the simplest thing to do is to either script around or perform certain dance with Makfile conditionals to have what's passed to `go build -o` to have `.exe` suffix only under `GOOS` set to `windows`.

Comment: Also, since `go build` without `-o` places the executable image into the current directory, you might `mv` the image after it was built to whatever place is needed. Using `-o` is clearer IMO but this appears to be a not really beautiful solution in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `go install` for cross compiling. Use `go build` with `-o` flag.

[Here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17896) is some history regarding GOBIN, robpike posted an issue stating *"I have $GOBIN set but the go tool is ignoring it when installing..."*

[This article](https://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5) mentions

*"When cross compiling, you should use go build, not go install. This is the one of the few cases where go build is preferable to go install...
The reason for this is go install always caches compiled packages, .a files, into the pkg/ directory that matches the root of the source code...
This logic also holds true for the standard library, which lives in /usr/local/go/src, so will be compiled to /usr/local/go/pkg/$GOOS_$GOARCH. This is a problem, because when cross compiling the go tool needs to rebuild the standard library for your target, but the binary distribution expects that /usr/local/go is not writeable.
Using go build rather that go install is the solution here, because go build builds, then throws away most of the result (rather than caching it for later), leaving you with the final binary in the current directory, which is most likely writeable by you"*

Comment: Use `go build -o` instead, and script the `.exe` suffix if GOOS is set to windows. Also see comments on the question

Answer (score 0):

you just need to define `GOBIN` full address, not the relative address

```bash
ROOT = $(shell pwd)
export GOBIN = ${ROOT}/bin
```

example for use `goose`

```bash
GOOSE = $(GOBIN)/goose
GOOSE_DOWNLOAD = $(GO) install github.com/pressly/goose/v3/cmd/goose@v3.16.0
db: ## goose
    test -e $(GOOSE) || $(GOOSE_DOWNLOAD)
    $(GOOSE)
```

example for use `golangci-lint`

```bash
LINT = $(GOBIN)/golangci-lint
LINT_DOWNLOAD = $(GO) install github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@v1.54.2
lint: ## Lint the files
    test -e $(LINT) || $(LINT_DOWNLOAD)
    $(LINT) version
    $(LINT) run
```

1. `GOOSE_DOWNLOAD` install your file in `GOBIN`
2. `test` to check exist an executable file or not if true run the below commands else run the install command and run the below commands.